# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_csv.reader' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import http.client
import time
import csv
import json
import codecs
import uuid
import pandas as pd
cols = ['ICCID',"Status Code"]
lst = []

i=1

input_file ="1.txt"
output_file ="Output File_Test.csv"
file = open(output_file, "w")
csv_writer = csv.writer(file,dialect='excel')

with open('1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    f1_read = csv.reader(f1)
    for var in f1_read:
        code = var[0]
        def luhn_checksum(code):
            length = len(code)
            parity = length % 2
            total_sum = 0

            for i in range(length-1, -1, -1):
                d = int(code[i])
                if i % 2 == parity:
                    d *= 2
                if d > 9:
                    d -= 9
                total_sum += d
                return total_sum % 10


        def luhn_calculate(partcode):
            checksum = luhn_checksum(partcode + "0")
            return 0 if checksum == 0 else 10 - checksum

        def luhn_validate(f1_read):
            return luhn_checksum(f1_read) == 0
res = luhn_calculate(f1_read)
res1= luhn_validate(f1_read)

print(res.partcode)

data = res.read()

file = open ("out.txt", "a+")
file.write(data.decode("utf-8") + "\n")
lst.append([str(sub_id),res.code])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)
df1.to_excel("Output_1397.xlsx")     
print("DONE!")
```

In above program failing with error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/JLR swapping/JLR WIRELESS CAR API_test.py", line 43, in

File "D:/JLR swapping/JLR WIRELESS CAR API_test.py", line 38, in Lehn _calculate
Type Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_csv. reader' and 'str'

Here we give input as one number '893107032131149492'without check digit. we require output as check digit.
trying to resolve but still facing issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
let
  Source = Folder.Files("C:\Mobility_reports_inputs_files"),
  #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Date modified", Order.Descending}}),
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each Text.StartsWith([Name], "Mob_repc", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ),
  #"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(#"Filtered Rows",1),
  Navigation1 = #"Kept First Rows"{0}[content]
in
  Navigation1
```

What are you wanting to do for the last step? I guessed above.

Comment: How did this go? If it did the trick then please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all.